# Почему не работает DI Laravel именно в одном контроллере?

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

Добрый день коллеги!

Возникли затруднения с laravel, в нем прекрасно работает DI и я с удовольствием его использую, но создавая очередной контроллер resource для админки, я не могу написать так:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param Keywords $keywords
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Keywords $keywords)
{
    dd($keywords);
}
```

Получаю просто модель пустую, вместо Keywords::findOrFail($id).

Метод show принимает $id и laravel должен автоматом распознать мою модель и засунуть в неё этот id, в других контроллерах это работает, но именно в этом нет..
Пробовал и чистить весь кэш, переименовывать модель и контроллер).

Причем пробовал в другом котроллере подставить эту модель и все вывелось прекрасно.
в роутинге так:

```
Route::resource('/keywords', 'KeywordsController');
```

Помогите понять почему именно в этом контроллере не работает DI

Вот сам контроллер, в котором проблема:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cabinet\Admin;

use App\Entity\Admin\Keywords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class KeywordsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param Keywords $keywords
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Keywords $keywords)
    {
        dd($keywords);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Если это Route::resource то у вас метод show должен выглядеть так
public function show($id, Keywords $keywords) и уже в контролере искать по id

Comment: Помогла документация разобраться почему di не хотел работать https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding